# Apache POI - Handling Empty fields

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am new to Apache POI, and I need to write to an excel file based on the contents of my DB. However, when there is an empty/null field in the DB, a Null Pointer Exception is thrown for that particular field. I've been reading about Missing Cell Policies, is this the best way to address this? I have omitted a lot of code for brevity, but the below is the key part. For example if actualAmountReturned is empty in the DB, a NPE is thrown.

```
        List<CaseData> cases = (List<CaseData>) model.get("cases");
    int rowCount = 1;
    for (CaseData pieCase : cases) {
        Row userRow = sheet.createRow(rowCount++);
        userRow.createCell(0).setCellValue(pieCase.getCaseId());
        userRow.createCell(1).setCellValue(pieCase.getAcknowledgementReceivedDate());
        userRow.createCell(2).setCellValue(pieCase.getActualAmountReturned());
}
```

Comment: Check if the value is defined, and only create+set the cell if it is?

Comment: What data type does `pieCase.getActualAmountReturned()` return?

Comment: @Gagravarr these are optional fields, so sometimes are present are sometimes aren't.

Comment: @AxelRichter its a Double

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are only two [Cell](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html)`.setCellValue` methods which will throw `NPE` when the given value is `null`. This are the two only ones which take primitive data types as `value` parameters but you put the appropriate object wrapper classes so unboxing is necessary. This are [Cell.setCellValue(boolean value)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#setCellValue-boolean-) and [Cell.setCellValue(double value)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#setCellValue-double-).
This is because unboxing from `Boolean` to `boolean` and `Double` to `double` fails for `null`.

For example

```
Boolean value = null;
cell.setCellValue(value); //NPE because unboxing `Boolean` to `boolean` fails
```

and

```
Double value = null;
cell.setCellValue(value); //NPE because unboxing `Double` to `double` fails
```

All other `Cell.setCellValue` methods which take non primitive data classes as `value` parameters simple create blank cells when `null` is given.

So if `pieCase.getActualAmountReturned()` returns a `Double`, then

```
...
if (pieCase.getActualAmountReturned() == null) {
 userRow.createCell(2).setBlank();
} else {
 userRow.createCell(2).setCellValue(pieCase.getActualAmountReturned());
}
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I did not appreciate the above with Double and Boolean. It is also the case when an object is used to declare a variable ie private Channels channel;

Comment: @Coder: Your comment does not make sense to me in context of that question. There is not a `Cell.setCellValue` method which takes a `Channels` object as the `value` parameter.

Comment: correct, I only copied a subset of the create and set values, as I have over 30. Didn't see the value in posting everything